# How to make a list from string values (dates in a cell separated by delimeter)

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have a table shown like this (there is only one column where all dates are written in one cell, separated by a delimiter). How to make a list of dates out of those values and calculate `MAX` and `MIN` value in a particular row?

```
values
1. 01. 2019;5. 07. 2016;3. 05. 2014;1. 04. 2019;7. 04. 2016
2. 01. 2019;6. 07. 2016;2. 01. 2019;3. 01. 2019;8. 04. 2016
3. 01. 2019;7. 07. 2016;4. 01. 2019;9. 07. 2016
8. 07. 2016;8. 07. 2016;9. 07. 2016;4. 01. 2019;10. 04. 2016
5. 01. 2019;3. 04. 2019;8. 04. 2016;11. 04. 2016
6. 01. 2019;2. 04. 2019;6. 01. 2019;6. 07. 2016
```

I tried to do `List.Max([values])`, but this doesn't work.

Comment: the table looks like this

Answer (score 1):

You can `Transform` each record of your single column to a `list` of dates, then add columns for the `Min` and `Max` values:

```
let
    Source = YourTable
    #"Listed Dates" = Table.TransformColumns(Source, {{"Column1", each List.Transform(Text.Split(_,";"), each Date.FromText(_))}}),
    #"Added Min" = Table.AddColumn(#"Listed Dates", "Min Date", each List.Min([Column1]), type date),
    #"Added Max" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Min", "Max Date", each List.Max([Column1]), type date)
in
    #"Added Max"
```

See https://pwrbi.com/so_56333087/ for worked example

Answer (score 0):

I would first add an Index column (to preserve the row context), then Split the **values** column, By Delimiter, into Rows (advanced option). This will produce a row for each delimited sub-string (date).

Then I would convert the resulting **values** column to a Date datatype using Change Type Using Locale. It might need some string manipulation first e.g. Replace spaces with empty strings.

Finally I would Group By the **Index** column (added above) while aggregating the Max and Min of the **values** column.